# Whats the connection in a ServiceBusTrigger?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

What is the connection that needs to be defined with my service bus trigger (topic) for my Azure Function?

The Run looks like this

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testtopic", "testsubscription", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
```

Is it the connection string for the Policy under Shared access policy of the ServiceBus (Endpoint:sb://...)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connection is the name of a variable which contains connection string to a bus. You need to keep this variable in Application Settings of your Function App (accessible through the portal) and locally in `local.settings.json` -  `{"Connection" : "Endpoint..."}`

Comment: local.settings.json, does this apply to published function in Azure?

Comment: No, you only need it for local development - it’s equivalent to application settings in the portal.

Comment: In "Application settings" of my functions app I've added "MyConnection" to Connection Strings of the ServiceBus. I use MyConnection as the connection but I'm not getting any  messages... Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testtopic", "testsubscription", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "MyConnection")]

Comment: 1. You can use https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer to look into a Service Bus whether messages are send to the right topic.

Comment: Additionally, in your Function App there is a "Test" window to the right of the editor window - it can be used to mock behaviour of the bus and "send" messages straight to your function. What's the result of this test?

Comment: Can I use ConnectionStrings: { Connection: "" } in any way? 
Perhaps like Connection = "ConnectionStrings__Connection" 
or is such a thing impossible?